# Method from another class doesn't call

Tags: c#, class, methods

I am trying to call a method from another class. `p.players()` is supposed to open up when I choose this menu option:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Enumfactory.Position choice;
        Enumfactory.Location location;
        Player p = new Player();


        Console.WriteLine("Please choose from one of the following:");
        Console.WriteLine("1. GoalKeeper");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Defender");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Midfielder");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Striker");
        choice = ((Enumfactory.Position)(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())));

        string exit = "";

        while (exit != "Y")
        {

            switch (choice)
            {
                case Enumfactory.Position.GoalKeeper:
                    //assigning the actual position
                    p.Position = Enumfactory.Position.GoalKeeper;
                    p.players();
                    break;
```

Here is my method from the class Player:

```
public string[] players()
    {
        List<string> PlayerList = new List<string>();
        Player player = new Player();
        string enterplayer = "";
        while (enterplayer == "Y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the teamnumber of your player");
            player.teamNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of your player");
            player.name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the surname of your player");
            player.surname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the age of your player");
            player.age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the goals the player scored");
            player.goalsScored = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            PlayerList.Add(player.teamNumber.ToString());
            PlayerList.Add(player.name);
            PlayerList.Add(player.surname);
            PlayerList.Add(player.age.ToString());
            PlayerList.Add(player.goalsScored.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to enter another player? Y/N");
            enterplayer = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        foreach (var item in PlayerList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("to view your player");
            Console.Write("{0}", item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        return player.players();
    }
```

Comment: I think your problem is `while (enterplayer == "Y")`. `enterplayer` will never equal 'Y'

Comment: Does the code hits the method? Or does it as above told don't hit the while loop?

Comment: thanks! I took out the while loop, it works now

Comment: Enums are also Zero based, but your menu is 1 based. Dunno if you account for that.

Comment: @computer10171, suggest you put your comment as the answer and the OP can then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The method is probably being called, it's just your while loop never runs. This is because `enterplayer` will never equal "Y", therefore the code in your while loop will never run (which makes it look like your method isn't being called).

Did you mean the following?

```
string enterplayer = "";
while (enterplayer != "Y")
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop in the way you've written it, will evaluate the condition before the first time it goes into the loop. You initialise `enterplayer` to `""`, so the first time the while condition is tested it returns `false` and never enters the loop. You can fix this in two ways, either by initialising `enterplayer` so that the condition is satisfied first time through:

```
string enterplayer = "Y";
while (enterplayer == "Y") // We set enterplayer to "Y" so this is true first time through
{
    // Your code to add a player goes here
}
```

...or, you can use a slightly different form of `while` loop, where the condition is evaluated at the end. This means that the code within the loop is always executed at least once, and then repeated as long as the `while` condition at the end is satisfied:

```
string enterplayer = "";
do // This always enters the loop code first time
{
    // Your code to add a player goes here
}
while (enterplayer == "Y")
```

Since your code is using the `enterplayer` variable to decide whether to add any more players, I'd prefer the second form, even though as a variant of the `while` construct it's probably less used than the former.